# Calculate the voltage and the current of a ideal diode

Tags: diodes

I need to calculate the circuit below. (The used diode in the schematics is not the same from the task we have to solve. In our task we work with a ideal diode.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo4fNN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In school we learned, that a ideal diode could be substituted with a normal voltage source with the forward voltage of the diode (in our case 0.7V). Now I am not sure how to solve this task and how would a general approach on solving such problems look like?

According to the solution, the voltage meter should show V = 3.975V and I = 198.75uA

Comment: Are you positive you're supposed to use an "ideal diode"? Why do you talk about a forward voltage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is clear that the diode is forward biased, it acts as a short circuit but with a constant voltage drop. So you can replace the diode with a 0.7V and the circuit can be redrawn as shown.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr15gW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now it is just a matter of writing and solving two linear equations.

Answer (score 2):

Let the voltage at the junction of R1 and R2 be V, then apply KCL to this junction. Hint: the current through R3 is (V-0.7)/20k

Comment: Chu, just a suggestion. In your equation, the denominator "20 [ma]", looks like you're saying to divide by 20mA. I know that you're really just indicating that the answer will be in mA, but it's a little confusing at first glance.